# Why does SonarQ say 'Using' block does not dispose?

Tags: vb.net, sonarqube

Here is what Sonar is saying:

```
  EnsureLocalDisposalRule      Open      Updated: 6 days      Technical debt: 1 hours   
  Local 'da' of type 'SqlDataAdapter' is not guaranteed to be disposed of.
```

Here is the code:

```
    conn1.Open()
    Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(qry, conn1)
        'fill data set 1 for combobox
        da.Fill(ds1)
    End Using

    ds1.Dispose()

    With CompanyCbx
        'what the user sees
        .DisplayMember = "CMPNY_NM"
        'value behind each display member
        .ValueMember = "CMPNY_SEQ_ID"
        .DataSource = ds1.Tables(0)
        .SelectedIndex = 0
    End With
    'close connection
    conn1.Close()
    'Dispose connection
    conn1.Dispose()
```

The documentation regarding the `Using` block states that it disposes of whatever it is 'using,' so I don't understand the error.

Here is Sonar's documentation:

**EnsureLocalDisposalRule**

This rule checks that disposable locals are always disposed of before the method returns. Use a 'using' statement (or a try/finally block) to guarantee local disposal even in the event an unhandled exception occurs. 
Link to the official Mono Gendarme documentation

Comment: You should ask your question on the commercial support list because VB.NET is a commercial plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that this is just a bug in Sonar's analysis.  C# and VB.Net generate slightly different IL for logically the same `using` code and this difference often throws off decompilers.  Generally they are tuned for C# code and miss the subtle difference in VB.Net and hence believe it to be a manual `try / finally` instead of `using`

The key difference is that the VB.Net `null` check in the `finally` is more complex than the C# one.

C#

```
IL_000b: ldloc.0
IL_000c: ldnull
IL_000d: ceq
IL_000f: stloc.1
IL_0010: ldloc.1
IL_0011: brtrue.s IL_001a
```

VB.Net

```
IL_000c: ldloc.0
IL_000d: ldnull
IL_000e: ceq
IL_0010: ldc.i4.0
IL_0011: ceq
IL_0013: stloc.1
IL_0014: ldloc.1
IL_0015: brfalse.s IL_001e
```

C# essentially takes the result of `ceq` and branches on that while VB.Net takes the result, inverts it and then branches on false.  Functionally it does the same but the subtle difference often throws off code analysis

Comment: Very interesting - where did you find this? Thanks for the answer, by the way. I think after the `End Using` I had tried `.Dispose()` and that squelched the error. Can't recall 100% without being on my work cpu, though.

Comment: @Newbie i used to work on the managed compilers team hence I'm familiar with things that can throw off code analyzers :)

Comment: Impressive. You know a million x more than me, then. Thanks for the help man.